Accessing schema name in filter condition
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
@FilterDef(name = "MyTable.current")
@Filter(name = "MyTable.current", condition = """
    revision_number = (select max(v.revision_number) from {h-schema}my_table as v where id = v.id)
            """)
public class MyRevisioneEntity extends PanacheEntityBase {
  @Id
  /* This is NOT autogenerated */
  UUID id;
  @Id
  @Column(name = "revision_number")
  long revision;
  @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @Formula("(revision_number = (select max(v.revision_number) from {h-schema}my_table as v where id = v.id))")
  boolean latestRevision;
  // ... metadata, target of revision!
}

Above my domain,a simple entity identified by an UUID, can have multiple revisions.
Normally I need only most recent revision so I decided to create a filter MyTable.current but I have a problem, the {h-schema} placeholder is not resolved so I have to forge schema in filter condition.
The same condition applied as @Formula to property latestRevision works flawlessy (placeholder is resolved as expected).
Is this by design or @Filter condition should resolve placeholder as @Formula does?

I don't think {h-schema} is supported here... Though maybe it should be; feel free to create a feature request: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH
In the meantime, you could try simply using @SqlFragmentAlias:
@Filter(name = "MyTable.current", condition = """
    revision_number = (select max(v.revision_number) from {mytable} as v where id = v.id)
            """,
    aliases = @SqlFragmentAlias(alias = "mytable", table = "my_table"))
public class MyRevisioneEntity extends PanacheEntityBase {

See also https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter-sql-fragment-alias.
BTW, you might want to consider using Envers instead of rolling out your own solution.

EDIT: the suggestion below doesn't work, see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-18152
@Filter(name = "MyTable.current", condition = """
    revision_number = (select max(v.revision_number) from {mytable} as v where id = v.id)
            """,
    aliases = @SqlFragmentAlias(alias = "mytable", entity = MyRevisioneEntity.class))
public class MyRevisioneEntity extends PanacheEntityBase {

See also https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter-sql-fragment-alias (though that section doesn't seem to mention entity =, so perhaps it's outdated).

Using entity annot leads to this exception during session factory bootstrap:
org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: MyRevisioneEntity
at MappingMetamodelImpl.getEntityDescriptor(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:394)
at FilterConfiguration.mergeAliasMaps(FilterConfiguration.java:81)
at FilterConfiguration.getAliasTableMap(FilterConfiguration.java:56)
at FilterHelper.(FilterHelper.java:76)

Hmm, figures. Undocumented and broken, then. Maybe @SqlFragmentAlias(alias = "mytable", table = "my_table")?

Produces invalid SQL because table in subquery should be my_table and not its alias in main query
select
mre1_0.id,
mre1_0.revision_number
from
my_table mre1_0
where
revision_number = (
select
max(v.revision_number)
from
mre1_0 as v
where
id = v.id
)

Regarding jira issue: not only self-reference doesn't wotk but also referencing any other entities not builded during bootstrap phase (eg 2 entities both with @filterdef and one entity references the other one)
